# Javascript rating system

Tags: javascript, rating

I am not a javascript guru so please be patient with me.

I was looking for a good rating with js and I ran to the his blog:

http://www.marcofolio.net/webdesign/jquery_quickie_colourful_rating_system_with_css3.html

The author has a demo and has provided the code to download.

it looks really nice except the fact that it doesn't have the example for saving the colors. Therefore the colors are back to black (default color) once user moves the mouse away.

any idea how to have the colors fixed?

Comment: do you have the jQuery Color plugin? http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/color

Comment: Yes I do. I followed TimDog's suggestion. It doesn't revert the colors back to black anymore but when I go from high to low rating it doesn't change the higher rating colors. so I guess i have to revert all of them to their default color and then based on the vote color them again? do you have a better suggestion or solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the code TimDog has added:

adding

```
_rated = false;
```

to

```
$(".fav_rating li label").hover(function() {
```

resets the colors every time user hovers over the ratings. Then when they click _rated is set to true and therefore prevents the color change

in addition, i used a hidden input in my form that will contain the value of the rating. To do this my .click looks like following:

```
$(".fav_rating li label").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    _rated = true;
    $("#item_fav_rating").val($(this).parent().index() + 1)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way -- I took a closer look at the `script.js` in the example code:

Add this global variable under `animationTime`

```
var _rated = false;
```

The colors are reset here -- see how I've used the `_rated` variable?

```
// Restore all the rating to their original colours
if (_rated) $("#rating li a").stop().animate({ backgroundColor : "#333" } , animationTime);
```

Then in your click handler:

```
//Prevent the click event and show the rating
$("#rating li a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    _rated = true;
    //alert("You voted on item number " + ($(this).parent().index() + 1));
});
```

This will keep the colors highlighted. It will be reset when you refresh the page or rerun the reset animation line above.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Does that work when they go from a higher rating to a lower rating?

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. That works great and it prevent colors to go back to original. However if you go from high rating to low it doesn't restoer the high ratings to original. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I havent seen the code of the blog you mentioned, but it seems when user clicks on any button it is showing alert ie, onclick() is used. so you can have one global variable which will save the number and there itself you can add code to keep the color.